# How do I link a widget to a function in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

This is my current code. I am looking to link the buttons I made to open a new window. I want the old Window to then close. When the new Window opens, how do I go about creating a new interface for that Window.

Code:

```
import tkinter as tk

HEIGHT = 950
WIDTH = 650

root=tk.Tk()

canvas = tk.Canvas(root, height=HEIGHT, width=WIDTH)
canvas.pack()

frame = tk.Frame(root, bg='#80c1ff')
frame.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.1, relwidth=0.75, relheight=0.1, anchor='n')

button = tk.Button(frame, text="Credit Score Checker")
font = ("Helvetica",20,"bold")
button.place(relx=-0, relheight=1, relwidth=0.27)

button = tk.Button(frame, text="Financial Advisor")
font = ("Helvetica",20,"bold")
button.place(relx=0.25, relheight=1, relwidth=0.27)

button = tk.Button(frame, text="Insurance Planner")
font = ("Helvetica",20,"bold")
button.place(relx=0.5, relheight=1, relwidth=0.27)

button = tk.Button(frame, text="Goal Setter")
font = ("Helvetica",20,"bold")
button.place(relx=0.75, relheight=1, relwidth=0.26)

lower_frame = tk.Frame(root, bg='#80c1ff', bd=10)
lower_frame.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.25, relwidth=0.75, relheight=0.6, anchor='n')

label = tk.Label(lower_frame, text="Summary of finances", bg='grey')
label.place(relx=0.5, rely=0, anchor='n', relwidth=0.9, relheight=1)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of a button that opens up a new window when clicked I hope this helps

```
from tkinter import *

main = Tk()
main.geometry("1000x1000")
main.title("Welcome")
canvas = Canvas(main, width = 1500, height = 1000, bg = "spring green")
canvas.place(relx = 0.5, rely = 0.5, anchor = CENTER)


frame = Frame(main)
frame = Frame(main, width = 500, height = 500, bg = "cyan")
frame.place(relx = 0.5, rely = 0.5, anchor = CENTER)

frame3 = Frame(main, width=300, height=300, bg="orange")
frame3.place(relx = 0.5, rely = 0.5, anchor = CENTER)

# LABEL:

lbl = Label(main, text = "Hi", fg = "deep pink", font = ("Fixedsys",30), bg = "spring green")
lbl.place(relx = 0.5, rely = 0.5, anchor = CENTER)

# FUNCTION FOR BUTTON:

def on_click():
    root = Tk()
    frame2 = Frame(root)
    frame2 = Frame(root, width = 1000, height = 1000, bg = "cyan")
    frame2.place(relx = 0.5, rely = 0.5, anchor = CENTER)
    root.geometry("700x700")
    root.title("SUP")
    label_new = Label(root, text = "There you go :)", font = ("Fixedsys", 22), fg = "red", bg = "black")
    label_new.place(relx = 0.5, rely = 0.5, anchor = CENTER)

# BUTTON:

btn = Button(main, text = "this is a button", fg = "blue", font = ("Fixedsys",20), bg = "dark turquoise", command=on_click)
btn.place(relx = 1.0, rely = 0.0, anchor = NE)

main.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to create a new window every time the button is pressed and display the new widgets on this window, then the other answers provide an excellent solution. But rather than create a new window to display the new widgets, I would recommend simply destroying the old widgets on the current window and putting up the new ones on the same window. It has the same effect as "closing the old window and creating a new one".
To destroy all the widgets on the screen, simply write a function like this and call it whenever you want to remove all the old widgets and put up new ones.

```py
def clear() :
    for widget in root.winfo_children() :
        widget.destroy()
```

The above function iterates through all the widgets that have been put up on the window and destroys them, one by one.
Here is an example code to illustrate how this works.

```py
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.config(bg="#424242")

def clear() :
    for widget in root.winfo_children() :
        widget.destroy()

def window1() :
    clear()
    lbl1 = tk.Label(root,text="Hey there! Im part of window1!!",fg="white",bg="#424242")
    lbl1.pack()
    lbl2 = tk.Label(root,text="Im also a part of window1!!",fg="white",bg="#424242")
    lbl2.pack()
    btn1 = tk.Button(root,text="Press me to display window2",command=window2,fg="white",bg="#424242")
    btn1.pack()

def window2() :
    clear()
    lbl1 = tk.Label(root,text="Hey there! Im part of window2!!",fg="white",bg="#424242")
    lbl1.pack()
    lbl2 = tk.Label(root,text="Im also a part of window2!!",fg="white",bg="#424242")
    lbl2.pack()
    btn1 = tk.Button(root,text="Press me to display window1",command=window1,fg="white",bg="#424242")
    btn1.pack()

window1()

root.mainloop()
```

Here, as Cool Cloud has already said, a `command` parameter is passed to the button with the next function to be called. Both the functions,`window1` and `window2` call the `clear` function first which effectively clears the screen ,and then the new widgets are put up on the window.